# How to integrate TFS with embedded development

Tags: visual-studio-2010, embedded

In our company, we have two main development environment. One uses VS2010 for C# and C++ development, the other uses Code Composer from TI (not the newest Eclipse based, and no, I cannot upgrade it right now).

Some of the C++ code is shared between VS solution and the embedded solution.

I'm in the process of upgrading our VSS to TFS, and so far everything is a bliss, but it is going to be a hard sell telling my EE engineers that they need to install VS2010 to perform source control.

I'm installing the TFS 2010 Power Tools right now, but the bad reviews scare me.

So, what's the best way to perform this integration?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the engineers licensed with TFS and then use the explorer to have them check in and out, if Visual Studio scariness is the main issue. The explorer is very lightweight compared to Visual Studio.

As for the power pack, it is an installation on top of VS or the Explorer, unless you are talkinga bout TFPT.exe, which is a command line tool to be able to work with source code. I would not head that way, although engineers might be brainiac enought to love the DOS/UNIX like syntax. :-)